# Is it possible to add a stopover or intermediate waypoint in Google Maps navigation?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-navigation

On the desktop version of Google Maps, I can add multiple destinations, or drag the route created to include a specific spot that is not on the original route.   Is there a way to do this on the Android version of Maps, short of navigating to the first spot, and then entering the final destination once that's reached?

I'm running Maps version 5.11.0

Comment: A decent workaround, as suggested on [droidforums.net](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-general-discussions/9202-can-you-add-destination-navigation-im-missing.html): add your destination/route to My Maps via a PC. From your phone, select Layers > My Maps from the Google Maps App.

Comment: I can bring the map up with the route showing, but I don't see how to get it to navigate using that route.    When I select Navigation, it asks me to choose a destination and re-calculates the route.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. On Google Maps, create your trip including all waypoints.
2. Save that map to "My Maps" within Google Maps.
3. On the Android device, go to Maps, layers, more layers and then choose "My Maps"
4. Select the map you want, it will come into maps on your Android device with each waypoint available.
5. You can choose each waypoint individually and you will get the blue arrow over it which will kick off Google Navigation.

Not the best solution (e.g. Google having programmed it as a feature), but at least one can completely plan a trip with Google Maps and then port the entire thing over to the Android device and navigate with it.

Comment: Note for posterity: the newer version of Google Maps on the web doesn't allow for the creation of custom maps.

Answer (score 2):

Simple steps on Android phone.   Search for route on Android phone. Click on start Navigations button with whatever route it is suggesting.  Then Magnifying symbol will appear.  Tap on the magnifyling  symbol.  "Search along route"  will appear.  Here type the point through which the map should navigate and click on the name once it appears.  Now your new suggested route navigation will appear.

This is the simple and best step.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out the following while I was trying to plot a more scenic route just minutes ago (mind blown!):

1. I plotted a route in Chrome (PC) with waypoints
   (I did click the 'Share or Embed map' link hidden under the cog icon in the down right corner - but this isn't even necessary I think)
2. I opened my Chrome browser's history on Android and chose the most recent Google maps url I visited (you could also just bookmark it, or copy paste via eg. email or eg. Pushbullet app)
3. I chose 'Open with Maps' upon selecting the link and somehow magically the route WITH WAYPOINTS shows up, ready to click 'Start navigation'

*Woohoo, welcome scenic route in Mobile Maps navigation!*

Details about my 'setup':

- I'm running Fedora Linux (21) on laptop with Chrome latest beta: Version 42.0.2311.82 beta (64-bit) - for all I know, this should work no matter what OS as long as you have an updated Chrome version, beta or not
- I'm using the latest Maps UI in Chrome
- I have Lollipop on my Sony Xperia Z2 (alltough keeping Maps up to date should be sufficient)
- I have my history synced (obviously)

Below are the links with and without waypoints:
Default suggested route: [Lijnwaadstraat to Brusselsesteenweg (Belgium)](https://www.google.be/maps/dir/Lijnwaadstraat,+9000+Gent/Brusselsesteenweg,+Melle/@51.0331712,3.6956075,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x47c371a622ed23cb:0x9da25fba93b6232a!2m2!1d3.6872708!2d51.0687218!1m5!1m1!1s0x47c3759632b9bf0f:0xd58fab35d58e1519!2m2!1d3.7950629!2d51.0070742)
Route with waypoints: [Scenic version of the above ;-)](https://www.google.be/maps/dir/Lijnwaadstraat,+9000+Gent/Brusselsesteenweg,+9090+Melle/@51.0369243,3.7100594,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m29!4m28!1m20!1m1!1s0x47c371a622ed23cb:0x9da25fba93b6232a!2m2!1d3.6872708!2d51.0687218!3m4!1m2!1d3.7453674!2d51.053169!3s0x47c376b423c2506b:0x1c4329a3582fd264!3m4!1m2!1d3.7731719!2d51.0409503!3s0x47c3769b65f52371:0xe93f58b3f79ce566!3m4!1m2!1d3.7948943!2d51.0277084!3s0x47c375d13e2b4423:0x74a2e9aea66dc3e5!1m5!1m1!1s0x47c375bb17add831:0xfeb63bea473a0d63!2m2!1d3.7992553!2d51.0043073!3e0)

Can anyone confirm this is actually happening and not a figment of my imagination? ;-) - Google product forums confirmed this works (see last edit below)
Open the links above (they are safe, real Google Maps links from google.be) with your Android, chose 'Open with Maps' if asked.  The first one should take you there in about 17 minutes over mostly (sub)highways, the second one should take around 34 minutes and be completely different.

Sorry for stumbling upon this 3 year old question..  I'm happily plotting more scenic routes and bookmarking them ;-)

*- edit -*
[This link on Google product forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/maps/DwPoT0pklas%5B1-25%5D) contains a lot more information on this and I still need to confirm what will happen if I deviate from my custom route, triggering Maps Navigation into recalculation.  Will it recalculate to my next waypoint or straight to the destination (hence losing any further waypoints ahead)?  I just need to test this, tomorrow ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool which allows you to do just that.

https://mapped.me