# How to add a waypoint by tapping on the map?

Tags: google-maps, maps

I have a regular route for which I have two options through two highways. The two options are very close in terms of distance and time. But, when using the Google Map application, it usually gives me only one of these options, and unfortunately, it is not the one I prefer. What's worse, the app does not show the driving conditions on the other one, so I can't see if there is a delay or something, and driving from the other way is kind of a "leap of faith".

On the desktop, Google Maps website, I can add a waypoint on whatever route I chose using the mouse. But I could not find a way for doing that on the phone. I know I can add a destination, but this needs to be a specific address or location. I want to simply point at a point on the highway and get the route to go through that point. (Another thing is to add the point after the trip started. You need to stop the car to enter the new waypoint as a full search)

**Is there a way to add a waypoint by tapping (or another gesture) on the map?**

Note: I found [this related question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/15058/1965), but the answers seem to assume a preliminary preparation of the route.